# std::function copy and memory corruption

Tags: c++, std

I have a memory corruption in my program. The `driver_s2lp::_conf.rxtx` object gets corrupted, after a while (involving some `new` and `delete`) in my program.

```
class driver_s2lp
{
public:
    struct conf
    {
        std::function<std::vector<uint8_t>(std::vector<uint8_t> &data, size_t len)> rxtx;
        //there are other variables here
    };

    driver_s2lp::driver_s2lp(conf config)
    {
        _conf = config;
    }

private:
    conf _conf;
};

class s2lp_custom_ikm : private driver_s2lp
{
    struct conf
    {
        std::function<std::vector<uint8_t>(std::vector<uint8_t> &data, size_t len)> rxtx;
        //there are other variables here
    };

    /* can I safely copy the std::function like this ? */
    s2lp_custom_ikm(conf configuration) : driver_s2lp([configuration]() {
                                              struct driver_s2lp::conf driver_conf;
                                              driver_conf.rxtx = configuration.rxtx;
                                              // other copies here
                                              return driver_conf;
                                          }())
    {

        this->configuration = configuration;
    }

    void do_something()
    {
        // it seems that driver_s2lp::_conf.rxtx can be broken here
    }
};

int main()
{
    s2lp_custom_ikm::conf s2lp_config;
    s2lp_config.debug = [](std::string s) { printf("%s",s.c_str()); };
    //other std::functions here

    s2lp = new s2lp_custom_ikm(s2lp_config);

    s2lp->do_something()

    while(1){};
}
```

I wonder if there is something wrong with copying `std::function` as I do in the constructor of the `s2lp_custom_ikm` class?

I'm not sure it is relevant but it is the `m_invoker` which gets corrupted in the `std::function` object when I add a watchpoint in the debugger.

The problem may be somewhere else but I want to be sure the copy is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes, std::functions can be copied. Or moved. Make sure all the variables in the configuration have copy and move constructors that aren't broken.

Comment: There is to many omissions in included code to figure out what is the problem. Most common mistake is invoke `std::function` when calling it leads to destruction of object which holds it.

Comment: please provide a [mre], your code is nowhere near compilable

Comment: It needs two includes and a couple of trivial fixes; hardly "nowhere near compilable" @Alan. [Fixed](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f6c2ce6c4985fde) (took me about 45 seconds)

Comment: In fact there's nothing wrong with asking a simple starting question to _potentially_ save the trouble of creating a reproducing MCVE, which can be time-consuming. This post is easy to answer. Indeed, I have done so.

Comment: @MarekR Are we sure that's illegal? I can't find any wording to corroborate it in the standard.

Comment: @MarekR I have decided to ask this as [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62939957/4386278). Feel free to chime in. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if there is something wrong with copying std::function as I do in the constructor of the `s2lp_custom_ikm` class?

No.

The `std::function` copies in your constructor (both the initialiser and the body) are safe.

The program snippet shown does not contain a bug capable of the symptoms you report.

Comment: As an aside, that's a lot of copies you don't need. Consider throwing some moves and references in there.

Comment: Thanks @Asteroids With Wings for the answer which is exactly what I was looking for. Sure I will optimize this, actually I wanted first to do a safer code using copies (though it did not prevent me to find bugs !)

Comment: @VictorCANOZ Fair